# Reliable message protocol with only 2 bits as data

Tags: serial-port, bit-manipulation, bit

I have severe hardware limitations on a school project. To add a feature we desire, I am limited to 2 bit communication between two micro controllers. They share two wires that can independently go low or high.

If I wanted to send the string "Hello World" hex encoded across the wire, what protocol would ensure the message arrived safely and with minimal loss?

Comment: they have a common ground independent of the two wires?  you can use standard serial if you can hook those pins to the UART of the micro?

Comment: the micro has no UART.

Comment: are the lines open collector?

Comment: I'd try binary encoding with 1-bit parity.

Comment: The two basic options are emulating serial (uart) with one wire in each direction (which has the advantage that each end sends on one wire and receives on the other, so no risk of collision, and also you can get transmit working separately from receive, perhaps you can use a PC RS232 port with a TTL<>RS232 converter to substitute for either a receiver or transmitter), and using I2C protocol (which has the advantage of being self-timing but will be harder to get working/debug because both ends need to work to complete a transfer)

Answer (score 0):

I2C ( I squared C ) is a easy to bitbash synchronous protocol that has collision detection but requires open collector lines as multiple devices could be driving the lines at the same time.

Otherwise You can bit bash serial you just have to find a slow enough baud rate where it's reliable if you only have software delays to control timing with

On top of that then have a protocol something like

```
STX <DATA> ETX <CRC>
```

You can make this more complex as needed.  For instance sometimes it's way nicer if you can say up front how big the message is `<STX> <LENGTH> <DATA> <ETX> <CRC>`